# How to write a void function for different Structs/Containers with a template?

Tags: c++, templates

For instance I have a function

```
void func(my_cont &C){
  
    C.membA = 1;
    C.membB = 2;
 
    dosomething_with(C);
}
```

Also what to do in the function, if I have a Struct that does not have a member B?

Comment: I don't think anyone here can tell you what to do with a struct that does not have a `membB`. You have to decide that, and then (maybe) we can tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: Anyway, ignoring the issue with `membB`, the syntax for a template function is simple enough `template <class T> void func(T& C) { C.membA = 1; C.membB = 2; dosomething_with(C); }`

Comment: @john I mean if there is no membB how can I check it before fill it with an value? Maybe there is some c++ magic that does it automatically without checking it manually?

Comment: So if there is no `membB` you want `C.membB = 2;` to be ignored but the rest of the code to be executed? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: This is my problem. you have said that you want to do *something* if there is no `membB`. It's definitely possible to use C++ magic to check that. But you haven't said yet what the *something* is. So it's hard to advise you on what the best approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to statically check for the existence of a `membB` member inside the template function.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func(T& C)
{
    C.membA = 1;

    if constexpr (requires() { C.membB; })
    {
        C.membB = 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        int membA;
    };
    struct B
    {
        int membA;
        int membB;
    };
    A a;
    func(a);
    B b;
    func(b);
}
```

Another way to get functionality that differs per type:
Using template specialization, as OP requested.

```cpp
struct A
{
    int membA;
};
struct B
{
    int membA;
    int membB;
};

template<typename T> void func(T&);

template<> void func<A>(A& a) {
    a.membA = 1;
}

template<> void func<B>(B& b) {
    b.membA = 1;
    b.membB = 2;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    func(a);
    B b;
    func(b);
}
```

Comment: This is a C++20 solution. The OP hasn't said what version of C++ they are using.

Comment: `requires` is a constexpr bool expression, so you can [`if constexpr(requires(){ C.membB; })`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e36d6652114d9248)

Comment: @Caleth Ah that's nice, didn't expect it to have access to the function scope.

Comment: @Aedoro unfortunately I cannot use c++20 (only up to C++17). But the thing I am looking for is called template specialization I believe .

Comment: @Namal does this edit help you?